# Creating a progress bar for a search function

Tags: winforms, powershell

I am trying to make a progress bar in a powershell generated GUI that will show the progress of a search as the system caches all the groups in AD (there are about 12,000 so this just otherwise causes the system to hang for a short while)

I managed to build the bar etc but I cannot get it to fill the bar as the system adds the groups. Here is what I have so far:

```
[reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname("System.Windows.Forms") | Out-Null
[reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname("System.Drawing") | Out-Null

$Form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$Form.width = 345
$Form.height = 345
$Form.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"
$Form.ShowInTaskbar = $True
$Form.FormBorderStyle = 'FixedToolWindow'

$ExitButt = new-object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$ExitButt.Location = new-object System.Drawing.Size(235,5)
$ExitButt.Size = new-object System.Drawing.Size(100,20)
$ExitButt.Text = "Exit"
$Form.Controls.Add($ExitButt)
$ExitButt.Add_Click({$Form.Close()})

$Prog = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBar
$Prog.Maximum = 10000
$Prog.Minimum = 0
$Prog.Location = new-object System.Drawing.Size(50,50)
$Prog.size = new-object System.Drawing.Size(100,50)
$Form.Controls.Add($Prog)

$Button = new-object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$Button.Location = new-object System.Drawing.Size(120,100)
$Button.Size = new-object System.Drawing.Size(100,30)
$Button.Text = "Start Progress"
$Form.Controls.Add($Button)
$Button.add_click(
    {
    $GroupsList = Get-ADGroup -Server "server" -Filter *
    $Count = ($GroupsList | Measure-Object).Count
    $prog.Value = $Count
    }
    )
$form.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
```

Comment: Where are you updating the state of the progress bar?(You have to do this, it will not happen automatically).

Comment: I think that's the point where I'm struggling, is that i'm trying to drop the physical count into a variable, and then match the progress to that variable.

I can make a timer thats not an issue, but its trying to use the count in place of a timer

Answer (score 0):

To update a WinForms `ProgressBar` just set its `Value` property.

Eg.

```
# Initialisation...
$myProgBar.Minimum = 1;
$myProgBar.Maximum = 100;

# When something happens...
$myProgBar.Value = 50;
```

will set it to half way.

Comment: I edited the script slightly (see OP) but the problem is that it does nothing until it gets the final count, then just fills the bar in one jump

the issue is that I want it to increase as the number of groups the shell finds increases the value incrementally (so it looks like your typical loading bar)

Comment: @Sean You'll need to find an event (or something) that allows you to see incremental steps within the process. If it is a black box without any such progress data then you're out of luck (you can only show progress if you have progress to show). Also remember, if you are blocking the GUI thread UI updates will not appear.